# A relation between permanents and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I have skimmed this video that I found on mathoverflow:
http://tube.sfu-kras.ru/video/407?playlist=397

At about 15:05 the lecturer wrote down an equality
$\sum F(m_1, \ldots, m_m)z^{m_1}\ldots z^{m_m} = \frac{1}{det(zI - A)}$, where F is given in terms of coefficients of the $m$-by-$m$ matrix $A$. The definition of $F$ doesn't yet make much sense to me, but that's beyond the point.

My question is, how is this equality possible? the right hand side obviously has poles—the eigenvalues of $A$, but the left hand side is just a polinomial, it can't have poles! Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: well, it was actually
$\sum F(m_1, \ldots, m_m) z_1^{m_1}\ldots z_m^{m_m} = \frac{1}{det(z - A)}$.
Here I have abused the notation slightly: the z means actually the diagonalization of the corresponding vector. However, when you take $z_1 = \ldots = z_m$, the question still stands.

The domain is real, as I understand from the context of the lecture :), so the use of the term pole isn't really correct, I just forgot the right word in English :)

Comment: The LHS is not a polynomial; it's a power series.

Comment: Err... how? Can power series have singularities?

Comment: Take 1×1 matrices maybe. Sum(z^n,n=0…∞) = 1/(1-z).

Comment: @Jack, thanks for the example :)

Comment: Over what integers does the sum run? Does it allow negative integers?

Comment: I have no idea. Probably for all $m_i$ from $1$ to $\infty$ for the Jack Schmidt's example to hold.

Comment: Cool, it's Doron Zeilberger! If you had written that instead of just "the lecturer", this question would immediately have become more interesting. ;)

Comment: And the formula is, as mentioned in the video, MacMahon's Master Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacMahon_Master_theorem. The summation runs over all nonnegative integer vectors, but it appears that Zeilberger made a little mistake; it should be det(I-ZA), not det(Z-A). (Otherwise it doesn't even work for Z=0.)

Answer (score 1):

*From the comment by @HansLundmark above.*

---

The formula is MacMahon's Master Theorem, as mentioned in the video. The summation runs over all non-negative integer vectors, but it appears that Zeilberger made a little mistake; it should be $\det(I-ZA)$, not $\det(Z-A)$. Otherwise, it doesn't even work for $Z=0$.